# Creating a nested object structure from a list of data

Tags: java, list, loops, recursion

I have a list of data which appears something like this:

```
A [example 1]
B [example 2]
C [example 3]
C [example 4]
B [example 5]
C [example 6]
```

Each line of the text represents an object, belonging to the object type above it. I´d like to create a nested object structure to represent this, so a main class, A, will contain a list of B´s (example 2 and 5) and a class B will contain a list of C´s (example 2 will contain 3 and 4, example 5 will contain 6). A, B and C are depth indicators, A being the root node and any number of subsequent nodes being it's children. To clarify, each node will always belong to it's parent node directly above it, but there may be 0-many nodes. i.e it would be possible:

```
A [example 1]
B [example 2]
```

but not

```
A [example 1]
C [example 2]
```

since C must belong to it's parent B.

What I´m looking for is someone to point me in the right direction to find a neat solution for this (possibly though recursion?), it´s a large amount of data so ideally would like to iterate over the list just once, and anything I have done that seems nearly close to a solution is incredibly obfuscated.

Comment: Are `A`, `B`, `C` etc. depth indicators? It's not entirely clear what you want. There's no recursion in the *ingestion*, you just need to iterate and keep track of which node you're adding data to, e.g., push and pop.

Comment: Exactly, A would be the root node, B depth 1, C depth 2 etc. And you're right, I don't think recursion is what I'm after here, I'm looking for a neat way to keep track of the nodes I'm adding to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seemed to be really cool! I've tried it myself and I did come up with something. Please don't judge me for the code; it is a little bit messy, but I tried to solve it, too.

I'd understand your problem that you want a series of objects transform into a tree-data-structure...

The code assumes that you always have a list with the Structure A>B>C. So for example: A>C does not work. Additionally I assumed you always start with a root-Node A.

```
public class SO_Nested {

    public static class A {
        public List<B> classesOfB = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addTree(List<Object> objects) {

            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

                List<Object> addUnder = new ArrayList<>();

                B currentB = (B)objects.get(i);

                classesOfB.add(currentB);

                while(i < objects.size() - 1 && C.class.isInstance(objects.get(i + 1))) {
                    addUnder.add(objects.get(i + 1));
                    i++;
                }

                currentB.addTree(addUnder);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class B {
        public List<C> classesOfC = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addTree(List<Object> objects) {
            classesOfC.addAll(objects.stream().map(C.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    }

    public static class C {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> allClasses = generateClassesOfA();
        allClasses.addAll(generateClassesOfB());
        allClasses.addAll(generateClassesOfC());
        allClasses.addAll(generateClassesOfB());
        allClasses.addAll(generateClassesOfC());
        allClasses.addAll(generateClassesOfA());
        allClasses.addAll(generateClassesOfB());
        allClasses.addAll(generateClassesOfB());
        allClasses.addAll(generateClassesOfC());

        List<A> sturcture = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allClasses.size(); i++) {

            List<Object> addUnder = new ArrayList<>();

            A currentA = (A)allClasses.get(i);
            sturcture.add(currentA);

            while(i < allClasses.size() - 1 && !A.class.isInstance(allClasses.get(i + 1))) {
                addUnder.add(allClasses.get(i + 1));
                i++;
            }

            currentA.addTree(addUnder);
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }




    private static List<Object> generateClassesOfA() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 1).mapToObj((unused) -> new A()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static List<Object> generateClassesOfB() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 2).mapToObj((unused) -> new B()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static List<Object> generateClassesOfC() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 2).mapToObj((unused) -> new C()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem like a tree problem. You can have a class of Node, which will have list of Another Node.

```
class Node {
    public Node parent;
    public List<Node> children;
}
```

When ever you see succeeding alphabet you can move to child of current node and add the value to the children list. If you see preceding alphabet you have to come back to parent nodes.

Hope this helps you